# Javascript prototypical inheritance creates extra properties in the derived classes

Tags: javascript, inheritance

When I do inheritance in JS, I find extra properties in the derived classes that are duplicates of the base class properties; I can't guess how to force the derived class to use the properties of the base class. I need a little shove in the right direction so that I can fix my inheritance model or that I can change the way I am using prototypical inheritance.

Let's say that I start with this typical inherit function:

```
Function.prototype.inheritsFrom = function( parentClassOrObject ){
if ( parentClassOrObject.constructor == Function ) { 
    this.prototype = new parentClassOrObject;  //Normal Inheritance 
    this.prototype.constructor = this;
    this.prototype.parent = parentClassOrObject.prototype;
} else { 
    this.prototype = parentClassOrObject;      //Pure Virtual Inheritance 
    this.prototype.constructor = this;
    this.prototype.parent = parentClassOrObject;
} 
return this;
};
```

---

You've probably seen this before. Now I create the following inheritance:

```
function base() {
    this.id = 0;
};

base.prototype.init = function ( _id ){
    this.id = _id;
};

function entity(){
};

entity.inheritsFrom( base );

entity.prototype.init = function( _id ){
    this.parent.init.call( this, _id );
};
```

---

Now we use the entity class like follows:

```
var e = new entity();
e.init( "Mickey" );
console.log( e.id );
```

When I inspect the properties of my new entity class ... I now have two IDs (see output below). Obviously this is a trivial case, but I have spent a lot of time trying to get this to work.

```
e: entity
  id: "Mickey"
  __proto__: base
    constructor: function entity(){
    id: 0
    init: function ( _id ){
    parent: base
    __proto__: base
```

Why do I have two IDs? The derived class doesn't even reference the 'this.id' of the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `inheritsFrom` when you do `new parentClassOrObject` the base constructor invoked and `id` property setted to prototype. You need to change your method:

```
Function.prototype.inheritsFrom = function( parentClassOrObject ){
  if ( parentClassOrObject.constructor == Function ) {
    function tmp() {}
    tmp.prototype = parentClassOrObject;
    this.prototype = new tmp;  //Normal Inheritance 
    this.prototype.constructor = this;
    this.prototype.parent = parentClassOrObject.prototype;
  } else { 
    this.prototype = parentClassOrObject;      //Pure Virtual Inheritance 
    this.prototype.constructor = this;
    this.prototype.parent = parentClassOrObject;
  } 
  return this;
};
```